# How I can know if a point is inside of polygon from Android using Java

Tags: geometry, java

I have an app that use osmdroid and previously I make a polygon that is represented as array of points latlng.
I would like know if a point is inside of my polygon from Java Android. Any option for this?

Comment: like this? https://github.com/sromku/polygon-contains-point

Comment: I have geodesic coordinates for use this tool need converts data? what recomend me ?